# Shannon number upper and lower bounds

Tags: recreational-mathematics

What are the best proved upper and lower bounds for the Shannon number, i.e. number of possible positions of chess? Is the upper bound  7728772977965919677164873487685453137329736522 given in http://homepages.cwi.nl/~tromp/chess/chess.html generally accepted?

Comment: I wouldn't accept that number.    

First step -- calculate the number of possible pawn positions. For each position, have a minimum number of captures required to reach that position.  Also, calculate which pieces are nonmobile in a given position.

Second step -- for each pawn position, calculate the number of legal positions for the remaining mobile pieces. Not all positions will be reachable, but that doesn't matter for estimates.

Exercise -- no pawns moved or captured. How many positions are possible?

Comment: Do you have a particular reason for not accepting the number?